# Couldn't find source file src/talker.cpp(Tutorials\WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++))

Tags: ros, roscpp, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the tutorial--Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++),when I run make, the console show error(I've added the ros_workspace to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH):

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package beginner_turorials
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file src/talker.cpp; assuming that it is in /home/duxiaoshi/ros_workspace/beginner_turorials and will be generated later
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:471 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file "talker.cpp".  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp
  .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (rosbuild_add_executable)
```

I've added the ros_workspace to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH,why  src/talker.cpp still couldn't be found?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10908/couldn%27t-find-source-file-src/talker.cpp(tutorials%5Cwritingpublishersubscriber(c++))/) by [duxiaoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/959/duxiaoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-08-19**:
Needs more info. Could you post your code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without posting more information this question cannot be answered, please follow the guidelines here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0